# jQuery accordion like tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and a jQuery accordion. I have to do tabs in a similar style, using the accordion. I mean, the clickable items should to be inline (like the tabs style), and not like a list (one below the other).

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: When you click one of the tabs, do you want the sub-menu options to appear horizontally to the right, or vertically below, the main tab?

Comment: Thanks @borbesaur , I need vertically below, just like a tabs, with the only difference that clicking on the item can be closed again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your specific requirements, I think you need to use Syden's answer, with a tiny bit of customization.
Use bootstraps Collapse component.

```
<p>
 <a class="btn btn-primary btn1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
Link with href
  </a>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn2" type="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
Button with data-target
 </button>
   </p>
  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample1">
 <div class="card card-block">
Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
</div>
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample2">
 <div class="card card-block">
Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
</div>
</div>
```

then, with javascript, make a custom click function so that when you have one collapse open, it first hides all the others, then shows the one you clicked - so that you don't have to click twice.

```
$(".btn1").on("click", function(){
$(".collapse").collapse('hide')
$("#collapseExample1").collapse('show')
});
 $(".btn2").on("click", function(){
$(".collapse").collapse('hide')
$("#collapseExample2").collapse('show')
});
```

Note: you will need to add an on-click function for each of your buttons for this to work.

Comment: Your solution works in part, because when item closed they are correctly inlined, but when a panel is open all other items going down, under the opened panel (look: [link]http://imgur.com/a/d7pBR).

Comment: Yeah, that's what bootstrap accordion is, you click on a tab and all the sub-options appear below the main heading.  I even asked you, and you said you wanted the sub-options to appear below. --  " I need vertically below, just like a tabs, with the only difference that clicking on the item can be closed again" --
Where do you want them to go?

Comment: I'm sorry, perhaps I expressed myself badly. The items should remains always inlined (like a tab style), and all panels should open under (like this [link]http://imgur.com/a/ycFne )

Comment: Ahh, I understand.  See my edit above.  Accordion will not work for this, I have demonstrated how to customize Syden's answer so that it hides the open menu and shows a new 1 with just one click instead of 2

Comment: Now works good! ;) Is there any way to semplify the jquery script? To avoid putting all btns names and using only one class?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 bootstrap componentes to achieve that, tags & collapse.

[Tags (span)](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/tag/)

[Put tags inside collapse](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/)

Comment: Your solution is good, the problem is that "collapse panel" is individual, I mean that wdith multiple panels, when clicked once, It does not close the other panels opened and needs to double click.

Comment: Check this example: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/#accordion-example also note to load bootstrap js file as well.

Comment: Yes, but I need clickable items inlined horizontally not vertically (like tabs style, look this [link]http://imgur.com/a/ycFne )

Comment: I see, what about this one http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/#example ? you would still need to tweak a bit of CSS for some "tab-looking" aesthetics on the buttons, but the alignment and behavior is there.

Answer (score 0):

> I have to do tabs in a similar style, using the accordion. I mean, the clickable items should to be inline (like the tabs style), and not like a list (one below the other).

If I understand the question correctly, you can accomplish this by doing the following.

Wrap everything inside the `panel-group` as Bootstrap illustrates and just use an `<ul>` list with the class of `nav nav-tabs` for your links that target the div panels.

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist">
  <!-- Bootstrap Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs"> 
     <li><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne"></li>
     ...
  </ul>
  <!-- Bootstrap collapse -->
  <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        ...
     </div>
     ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Then remove the default panel borders

```
.panel-default {
  border: 0;
}
```

No need to add additional javascript, use what Bootstrap already provides.

Here's a working codepen for you to review. http://codepen.io/yongchuc/pen/YpZvOJ